# Watch for process start, then execute command

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch, script, task-scheduler

Short of hacking together a service to monitor process launches, is there any other way I can go about attaching code, or executing a command/process to an event handler for another specific process starting?

I have two conflicting applications. I want a service to run constantly, except when it detects the launch of a specific process, so I would like to attach code to process start and process exited events. Ideally i'd like some way which does not involve writing my own service to handle this feature, but i'm unsure if powershell or task scheduler are capable (or any other existing solution?).

Comment: I would start digging for the solution of your very intricate question, @paddywan, using [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script) that contains a two-line batch script. Basically, you could start detecting the execution of a process using commands such as the `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL` command and the `if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Program is running` command and see where you can go from there.

Comment: The powershell answer at https://superuser.com/questions/265168/how-do-i-check-if-a-programs-instance-is-running-or-not-before-running-that-pr could easily be wrapped in an infinite for loop (with a pause of some kind) to periodically check for the presence of a task and run something else.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved via powershell and task scheduler (use `powershell` as the process to run, and `-windowstyle hidden PATH_TO_PS1`)

```
while(1)
{
    $LBM = Get-Process "LittleBigMouse_Daemon" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $DRG = Get-Process "FSD-Win64-Shipping" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($DRG)
    {
        if($LBM)
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\LittleBigMouse\LittleBigMouse_Daemon.exe" -ArgumentList "--stop" #kill LBM
            Stop-Process -Name "LittleBigMouse_Daemon" -Force
            Write-Output "Killing LBM"
        }
    } else {
        if(-not($LBM))
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\LittleBigMouse\LittleBigMouse_Daemon.exe" -ArgumentList "--start" #Run LBM
            Write-Output "Starting LBM"
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```